# Call Javascript function and pass value from C#

Tags: javascript, c#

in HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function removeIndustry(item)
    {
        confirm(item);
    }
</script>
```

in C#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "<a href='javascript:removeIndustry('IndustryNameHere')'><i class='icon-remove'></i></a>Click";
}
```

The code is not working if I put any strings like 'IndustryNameHere' in that function. Without any values, it is working fine. Anyone please help me fix this error. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It could be because of the use of `'` single-quote for the parameter. Seems to me that these quotes are in conflict with each other. Can you share your resulting HTML of what you have currently? i.e. with this `IndustryNameHere` string in it.

Comment: Try using `&quot;` instead of single-quote for the parameters to be wrapped around with i.e. it should look like this: `"<a href='javascript:removeIndustry(&quot;IndustryNameHere&quot;)'><i class='icon-remove'></i></a>Click";`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to escape quotes with `\`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "<a href=\"javascript:removeIndustry('IndustryNameHere')\"><i class='icon-remove'></i></a>Click";
}
```